# Using helper methods in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some trouble realising how the helper methods should be used in views. For example, take these parts of code:

```
Mycontrollers_helper.rb

module MycontrollersHelper
    def destroy_everything
      Model.destroy_all 
      redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

How should it be used in the view then ? Let's say adding the method to a button in the view:

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy all', destroy_everything, method => :post %>
```

Is just writing a method in the helper.rb file enough or does it require some additional lines in the controller it refers to ? Is this even the correct syntax for something like this ?

Comment: You misunderstand helpers concept. This `destroy_everything` should be a controller action.

Comment: If you can supply some good source that explains this a bit I'd be really grateful, just can't find anything good to read about this.

Comment: Have you seen http://guides.rubyonrails.org?

Comment: I have, but I've only managed to find info on form helpers and things like that, I thought that I required helper methods to call additional methods from my views.

Comment: To be honest, I would advice you to start with some Rails tutorial, because views, controllers and routing are very basic things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helpers in rails actually view helpers. So they are meant to provide some help to render your views.

If you want to delete something, and then redirect to some action, just use a controller action for that.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are taking about view helper, which you want to call from your view template.

You can call your view helper with the name of the method.

Calling `destroy_everything` will works fine if this helper is included in your controller.

**Update:**
If you write your helper method in application helper then you don't need to worry about load/ include the helper.